# How to resample or interpolate data with gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, linear-interpolation

In some cases you might need to resample your data. How can this be done platform-independently with gnuplot? Below is one attempt.

The dataset `$Dummy` contains the interpolated values, however, with a lot of unnecessary lines containing `NaN`. The dataset `$DataResampled` finally contains the desired data.

My question is: can this be done simpler and faster?

**Script:**

```
### resampling data with linear interpolation
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0   1
1   4
2   10
5   15
10  5
20  11
EOD

# get the x-range
stats $Data u 1 nooutput
MinX = STATS_min
MaxX = STATS_max
Resamples=20
# or alternatively fix the step size 
# StepSize=1
# Resamples = int(MaxX-MinX)/StepSize+1

Interpolate(xi) = y0 + (y1-y0)/(x1-x0)*(xi-x0) 
x1=y1=NaN

# resample the data
set print $DataResampled
set table $Dummy
do for [i=1:Resamples] {
    xi = MinX + (i-1)*(MaxX-MinX)/(Resamples-1)
    Flag=0
    plot $Data u (x0=x1, x1=$1, y0=y1, y1=$2,\
        (xi>=x0 && xi<=x1 && Flag==0 ? (Flag=1, yi=Interpolate(xi), xi) : NaN)): \
        (Flag==1 ? yi : NaN) with table
    print sprintf("%g\t%g",xi,yi)
}
unset table
set print

set xrange[-1:21]
plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 6 ps 2 lc rgb "black" t "original data",\
     $DataResampled u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "web-green" t "resampled with linear interpolation",\
     $Dummy u 1:2 w impulses lc rgb "red" not
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Generally speaking, that is a bit away from gnuplot's typical usage. Arrays and such widen the programming-like capabilities, but gnuplot sticks more to the philosophy of Unix tools: do one thing, and do it properly. Usually one would use an external tool or script for resampling, like `plot '< resample.py'`, which is also platform independant. For your special case an implementation of `smooth linear` could be worth a feature request, but gnuplot will remain a plotting tool, and not a data processor.

Comment: ok, I partly agree. If I have to use external tools for very basic tasks of data preparation, e.g. like transposing, sorting, resampling, merging, appending or special file listings and additionally want to ensure platform independence by using Python, what would be the reasons **not** to switch to Matplotlib?
Don't get me wrong, I like gnuplot very much.

Comment: @Christoph, some time go, I placed a feature request for linear interpolation, i.e. `smooth linear` (https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/518/), however, no response so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preamble:** I'm aware that gnuplot wants to be a plotting program and not a data analysis or data processing tool. However, a few data handling functions would be useful, e.g. like linear interpolation/resampling of data. 
In gnuplot there are a few smooting options implemented check `help smooth`, but these are for smoothing noisy data with many datapoints.
There are: `smooth bezier`, `smooth cplines`, `smooth acsplines`, `smooth mcsplines`, `smooth sbeziers`, and since gnuplot 5.5. `smooth path` for [interpolating along a path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69041618/7295599). Something like `smooth linear` doesn't exist (yet) and seems to be [not interesting enough](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/518/) to be implemented.

One application example: 
 You have spectral raw data from a spectrometer with oddly spaced wavelengths, e.g.
`380.71, 383.53, 386.21, ...`
and you have a filter function at wavelengths `380, 382, 384, 386, 388, ...` and you want to multiply this data for each wavelength. So, you need to have the y-values of both datasets at identical x-values.
And of course, you could do it with an external program.

However, if it is not too complicated and not too inefficient why not doing it within gnuplot?
So, I think the following script is a fast **gnuplot-only** way for linear resampling/interpolation of data.

**Comments:**

- instead of the datablock `$InterpolX`, a file with arbitrary, irregular x-positions can be used
- the script is ["seriously" misusing the `smooth zsort` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77651596/7295599) to get the job done.
- it uses the angles (check `help atan2`) between two original data points stored in the 3rd column for calculating intermediate points later. The data will be sorted by x-values via `smooth zsort`
- the angles are ranging from `-pi` to `+pi` (or `-180` to `+180` degrees) depending on the `set angles {degrees | radians}` setting. Hence, the variable `OoR` (=out of range) is arbitrarily set to `999` to distinguish between original points and points which need to be interpolated.
- the variable `p` determines whether the original data points should be included or not
- for 2000 resampled datapoints, the script in OP's question takes about 80 seconds, whereas the following script takes about 0.06 seconds on my old laptop. For some strange reasons only in gnuplot 5.4.1 and 5.4.8 it takes 0.23 seconds, but about 0.06 seconds for the other versions tested.

**Data:** `SO54362441.dat`

```
0   1
1   4
2   10
5   15
10  5
20  11
```

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.4.0 July 2020)

```
### resampling of data via linear interpolation
reset session

FILE = "SO54362441.dat"

set table $InterpolX
    set samples 20    # set number of samples
    plot [0:20] '+' u 1 w table
unset table

set table $Temp
    plot x1=y1=NaN FILE u (x0=x1,x1=$1,x0):(y0=y1,y1=$2,y0):(atan2(y1-y0,x1-x0)) w table, \
         '+' every ::::0 u (x1):(y1):(0) w table, \
         OoR=999 $InterpolX u 1:(0):(OoR) w table
set table $Temp2
    plot $Temp u 2:3:1:1 smooth zsort lc var
set table $Interpolated
    p = 0    # include original datapoints? 0=no, 1=yes
    plot x1=y2=xb=yb=NaN $Temp2 u (x0=x1, x1=$3, y1=$1, a1=$2, \
         a1==OoR ? ( y2=yb+(x1-xb)*tan(ab) ) : \
         (ab=a1, xb=x1, yb=y1, y2 = x0==x1 ? y1 : p ? yb : ''), x1) : (y2) w table
unset table

plot FILE          u 1:2 w lp pt 7     lc "black"     ti "Original data", \
     $Interpolated u 1:2 w impulses    lc "web-green" notitle, \
     $Interpolated u 1:2 w p pt 6 ps 2 lc "red"       ti "Interpolated"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Let me compare this **gnuplot-only** workaround to a "real life" situation: you have a screwdriver and you want to open a bottle of beer. It's not perfect. But why going out of the house (maybe into the rain) and searching for a bottle opener? ;-)