# Gnuplot cspline interpolation dataset at specified points

Tags: gnuplot, interpolation

I have two files,
say file 1

```
x        y
0.0    1.0
1.0    2.0
3.0    5.0
```

and file 2

```
x
0.5
1.815
2.5
```

I want to get smooth cspline interpolation values of file 1, but on the x-axis as specified by file 2.
I know how we can set the table and sample size and get the output determined by sample size, but i want to have data points value at the points specified by second file. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: How many data points in each file we talking about?

Comment: Something like 1600

Comment: Do you not have any function which model the data? You could use `fit` command for this function and then find the wanted values.

Comment: Yes I have a model, between two data points I have a model. Can you explain via some simple example? and consider writing an answer?

Comment: @zephyr0110 Question answered? If yes, then please accept the answer otherwise specify in more detail what you are/were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a file named `data.dat` containing this:

```
#  x      y
 0.000  0.007
 1.111  0.013
 2.222  0.061
 3.333  0.164
 4.444  0.250
 5.556  0.273
 6.667  0.158
 7.778  0.061
 8.889  0.015
10.000  0.018
```

You know that this data are described by [Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function).
On `gnuplot` it can been written as:

```
g(x) = a*exp(-(x - b)**2/2*c**2)
```

Suppose yet you have another file named `x-values.dat` containing 
the values which you want interpolate.

```
# x
0.923
1.497
2.357
3.900
4.396
5.696
6.658
7.146
8.851
9.947
```

You can use `fit` command to find `a`, `b`, and `c` values which fits data.
At last you use the `x-values.dat` as input to Gaussian function.

```
# The Gaussian function
g(x) = a*exp(-(x - b)**2/2*c**2)

# Initial values 
a = 0.5     # Height of the curve's peak
b = 6.0     # Position of the center of the peak
c = 1.0     # Controls the width of the "bell"

set fit prescale    # Helps to fit if there are parameters that 
                    # differ in size by many orders of magnitude

# Performs the fit
fit g(x) 'data.dat' u 1:2 via a, b, c

# The graph itself:
# 1: Data points
# 2: Gaussian function after fit
# 3: Gaussian function using values from 'x_values.dat' as input
plot \
    'data.dat' u 1:2 w p pt 5 lc 'black' t 'Data',\
    g(x) w l lc 'red' t 'Gaussian',\
    'x_values.dat' u 1:(g($1)) w p pt 7 lc 'blue' t 'Interpolation'
```

[image: interpolated data]

Answer (score 1):

Of course, in best case you have a model (i.e. a function) which you try to fit to your data, like it's done in @grsousajunior's answer.
The case without model, but just taking interpolated values from the `cspline` curve at specified x-values, can be done via linear interpolation. The script below is adapted from here: [How to resample or interpolate data with gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54362441/7295599)

By the way, you can set the number of `cspline` points via `set samples`, default is `100`. So, you will have 100 `cpline` points in the datablock `$CSpline`, but if you want the values only at specified x-values (defined in `$InterpolX`) you might want to try the script below.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.4.0, July 2020)

```
### linear interpolation of c-spline data
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0.0    1.0
1.5    2.0
3.0    5.0
4.0    3.0
# 9.9    NaN
EOD

$InterpolX <<EOD
0.5
1.0
1.815
2.5
3.5
EOD

set table $CSpline
    set samples 100
    plot $Data u 1:2 smooth cspline
set table $Temp
    plot x1=y1=NaN $CSpline u (x0=x1,x1=$1,x0):(y0=y1,y1=$2,y0):(atan2(y1-y0,x1-x0)) w table, \
         '+' every ::::0 u (x1):(y1):(0) w table, \
         OoR=999 $InterpolX u 1:(0):(OoR) w table
set table $Temp2
    plot $Temp u 2:3:1:1 smooth zsort lc var
set table $Interpolated
    p = 0    # include original datapoints? 0=no, 1=yes
    plot x1=y2=xb=yb=NaN $Temp2 u (x0=x1, x1=$3, y1=$1, a1=$2, \
         a1==OoR ? ( y2=yb+(x1-xb)*tan(ab) ) : \
         (ab=a1, xb=x1, yb=y1, y2 = x0==x1 ? y1 : p ? yb : ''), x1) : (y2) w table
unset table

set offset 1,1,1,0

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc "black" ti "original data", \
     $CSpline u 1:2 w l lc "blue" ti "cspline", \
     $InterpolX u 1:(0):(0):(0.7) w vec lc "web-green" ti "x-values for interpolation", \
     $Interpolated u 1:2 w  p pt 6 ps 2 lc "red"  ti "interpolated cspline"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]